# IFERROR VLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

attempting to use a vlookup and an iferror in my VBA Coding.

I'm struggling to get my VLOOKUP to work. If i use it in the sheet, it works fine, using the VBA Code it isn't working, just returning a "#VALUE!" error.

```
option explicit

sub subname()

dim items variant

    item = wb.Sheets("EmpCal").Range("D" & SR).Value
    MsgBox item
    wb.Sheets("EmpCal").Range("E" & SR).Value = Application.VLookup(item, "Header!A:F", 5, 0)
end sub
```

I know this isn't showing the IFERROR. I originally had something along the lines of

`Application.WorkbookFunction.IFERROR(Application.Vlookup(item, "Header!A:F", 5, 0), "")`

But it returned nothing, obviously as it had the error! (This worked correctly!)

The MSGBOX Item worked, it displayed the correct search term.

Anyone able to point me into the correct direction please!

Comment: Please edit your title so you are not SHOUTING at us.

Comment: is it really shouting when that's the actual expression for the formula?

Comment: So if you respect the "actual expression for the formula" as you say, why isn't it in uppercase in your question text? And if the answer was helpful why haven't you voted for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VBA VLookup

- Note that there are better (more efficient) ways to do this.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Header")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A:F")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("EmpCal")
    
    Dim dItem As Variant
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim WannaCopy As Boolean
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 2 ' to make the example work
    
    ' For dr = x To y
    
        dItem = dws.Range("D" & dr).Value
        
        If Not IsError(dItem) Then
            dValue = Application.VLookup(dItem, srg, 5, False)
            If Not IsError(dValue) Then WannaCopy = True
        End If
            
        If WannaCopy Then
            dws.Range("E" & dr).Value = dValue
            WannaCopy = False
        Else
            dws.Range("E" & dr).ClearContents
        End If
    
    ' Next dr
    
    MsgBox "VBA Lookup has finished.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers, so you dont recommend using Application.VLookup ??? Is there any particular reason why?